# See/Log which javascript function is being executed by the browser

Tags: javascript, firefox

Is there a way/add-on that I can use so everytime *any* javascript function is executed in Firefox for example, the function name will be printed (to the console or where ever).

This is because I can't find (it's very hard to find) which function is executed when I click on a drop down.

So i want firefox/add-on to tell me the name of every javascript function that is being executed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the profiler of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Go to the console tab and click *Profile*. The profiler starts and all the javascript actions are "logged" till you click *Profile* again. Then you get the list of javascript functions that were executed in this interval.

A similar feature is available in most modern browsers' consoles.

Comment: What is the Chrome equivalent for this?

Comment: @Lijo Chrome has its own developer tools with a profiler. See View -> Developer -> Developer tools

Comment: I'm pretty sure the profiler doesn't log **all** function executions. It wakes up periodically and looks at the stack trace at this point. So if a function does not take a lot of time to execute, it will not show up in the profile.

Answer (score -6):

If you run chrome, hit f12 to bring up the developer window.  Under the Profiles you can list out the Javascript, CSS or Heap.  That's built in, so you don't need a plugin, not that anything is wrong with firebug, I'm just generally anti-Firefox